# get span children of a radio button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a row of radio buttons that is used for shipping charges. If a user clicks on a button, I am in need of collecting the two spans (the price and the cost ) that are contained in the div used used by the radio button element. All of the radio button share the same class called 'all-items' Here is the html:

```html
<li class="all-items">
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="usps_1" id="s_method_usps_1" checked="checked" class="radio">
<label for="s_method_usps_1" style="display:block; overflow:hidden;">
<span class="price">$30.20</span>
<span class="cost">Priority Mail </span>
</label>
</li>
```

Here is the jQuery I am working with.

```
         jQuery("input:radio[name=shipping_method]").click(function() {
         var shipping = jQuery(this).val();
         console.log(shipping);
         console.log(jQuery(this).find('span'));
         });
```

Comment: FYI, maybe mis-titled but as `input` is void element, it cannot contains any content. Here you want to use: `jQuery(this).next('label').find('span')`. Or better: `jQuery(this).closest('.all-items').find('.price, .cost')`

Comment: HI Wolf, would you mind putting that in an answer and I will accept that? that works great!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPAN aren't children of radio element. I'd suggest you to get the relevant LI parent and then target relevant SPANs, e.g:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.all-items').find('.price, .cost') // add specific SPAN classes if needed
```

I personnaly prefer it over `jQuery(this).closest('.all-items').find('span')` because this explicitely tell which specific SPANs you are looking for.